# Revoke Oauth2 Access programatically on Microsoft Identity platform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform, azure-identity

So what I am searching for is a Revoke oauth2 Access Endpoint Like Google's on Microsoft Identity platform.

Basically I have an App x which uses Microsoft identity platform and graph API to gain Access and use Users Mail,Calendar,contacts etc.

When the User want's their Microsoft Access to be removed from My app or wishes to delete their Account.

- i need to revoke the Access Token and Refresh Token I have and **My App Should be removed from the '[Microsoft Portal](https://account.microsoft.com)-> privacy -> Apps and Services That can Access your Data '**
  so that the user can be sure that the Integration is removed.

This feature is available with google's API's [Google Revoke Access Link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#tokenrevoke). So when i Hit this api with my refresh token all the access is removed and my App disappears from the '[google dashboard](https://account.microsoft.com)->apps which access your data' screen too.

Can you guys please help me find if this is Available with Microsoft's API and Point me towards it
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **[*Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0)** will  invalidate applications refresh tokens generated for  user which also invalidates tokens issued to session cookies in a browser for the user.

> **NOTE**: So if the user has access or granted access to the application, Azure AD will generate an access token which has
> alifetime of one hr.
>
> During this time even if app is deleted ,there are
> chances it is still available . Azuread issues a refresh token along
> with access token for the resource.
>
> If this is revoked ,the user wont
> be able to obtain the token again after the access token expires.

To revoke authorization in between the life span of the access token, please check below commands.

> The cmdlet operates by resetting the refreshTokensValidFromDateTime
> user property to the current date and time.

*Ex:*  ***using powershell***

```
PS C:\> Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId "a1dxxxxx-7xx6-4xxd-axxx-b7xxxxxxxa33"
```

- This command revokes refresh token of the specified user based on
  object id of user.

***Same operation using Microsoft graph API***

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/users/{userobject_id}/invalidateAllRefreshToken`
```

- Where as below command(powershell) revokes refresh token for current logged in
  user.

  `Revoke-AzureADSignedInUserAllRefreshToken`
- As the `admin` ,you can remove   user from the "Users and groups"
  section of the enterprise app.

[image]

- If the user has consented to the application to access app and if
  User assignment required? Is set to no under properties, then the
  user can directly go to portal and delete the app.

***The app will not be visible for that user when visiting the My apps portal in both the above cases.***

> Note:When user assignment is not required, unassigned users don't see
> the app on their My Apps.

You can use the following script to [***remove a user and role***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal#unassign-users-and-groups-from-an-app-using-powershell) from an application:

```
$user = get-azureaduser -ObjectId <objectId>
$spo = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId <objectId>
```

#Get the ID of role assignment which is assigned to user to unassign

```
$assignments = Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spo.ObjectId | Where {$_.PrincipalDisplayName -eq $user.DisplayName}
```

#below cmd  will show wha tall is assigned

```
$assignments | Select *
```

#In order to remove the Approle assignment check below command.

```
Remove-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spo.ObjectId -AppRoleAssignmentId $assignments[assignment #].ObjectId
```

References:

1. [Delete oAuth2PermissionGrant (a delegated permission grant) -
   Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. [Revoke user access in an emergency in Azure Active Directory -
   Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-revoke-access)

Comment: Thanks for the reply 

but The API that you've mentioned will invalidate all of their refresh tokens it seems. but i don't want that. 

To be clear:  I'm dealing mostly with Microsoft Personal Accounts here

1. in my case I just want my App to be gone from my users "connected 3rd party apps" screen on Microsoft portal.

2. The above [1] can be done manually by the user if he visits MS dashboard ->3rd party access -> and removes it there 

3. I'm just Asking if the [2] can be done Programmatically by the App itself before it deletes the refresh token