Programatically signing out of a Azure Identity Application
Previously I was able to do this to sign out of my app:
public async Task<bool> SignOut()
{
    var accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
    if (accounts.Any())
    {
        try
        {
            await PublicClientApp.RemoveAsync(accounts.FirstOrDefault());
            return true;
        }
        catch (MsalException ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex);
            Console.WriteLine("SignOut: See error log.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

But I am now using a DeviceCodeCredential.AuthenticationRecord. There is no account anymore.
What is the simplest way for a user to trigger to sign out?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72629012/2287576

You can increase the token lifetime or revoke the refresh token by resetting the refreshTokensValidFromDateTime

You can revoke authorization in between the life span of the access token OR increase the access token lifetime (can be increased to 24 hours)

@Rukmini if you look at the question I linked to, it has an answer there saying all your suggestions. But, in the comment to the answer the issue is raised that this approach affects all refresh tokens and not a specific use case.

Revoke-AzureADSignedInUserAllRefreshToken revokes refresh token for current logged in user

@Rukmini Yes, but won’t affect all apps? By all means provide me an equivalent SignOut using this technique and I will test. As it stands the other questions answer provides a lot of info and no complete solution.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

To programmatically signing out of an Azure Identity Application, you can make use of below endpoint:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/logout?client_id=ClientID&post_logout_redirect_uri=RedirectURL

As you have configured Multitenant application, you need to pass TenantID as common
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?client_id=ClientID&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms




Even after signout and not deleting the token file gets you this error "you have signed out of your account". And I could still log into outlook. So that is something. But My token is still valid so when I run my app a second time it still works" as the token is valid

This issue usually occurs when the token is still valid and hence you need to clear the token cache that is when a user signs out, you should remove the tokens associated with that user from the token cache All the user related token cache must be cleared with logout URL and then it will work.
Hence, first try to delete the token file and then sign out the user and the user will be signed out successfully.
public static void SignOut()  
{  
    // Ensure settings isn't null  
    _ = _settings ?? throw new System.NullReferenceException("The variable '_settings' should not be null");  
      
    // Delete the token cache file.  
    if (Path.Exists(Program.OutlookOptions.TokenCachePath))  
    {  
        File.Delete(Program.OutlookOptions.TokenCachePath);  
    }  
  
    // Logout  
    string url = 
      string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?client_id={0}", _settings.ClientId);  
    OpenUrl(url);  
}  

Reference:
How to open in default browser in C#

Thank you very much for all your help with this task. It is now working great!  Using the post_logout_redirect_uri did not seem to work for me. Perhaps the & should have been URL encoded. But it doesn't matter because I do not need a redirect anyway.

Great that I could help:)
