MSAL.Net Logout not exactly signing out
I am implementing sign in / sign out with Azure Entra Id (Azure AD) in my desktop application. Sign in works fine, but upon signing out, it clears the token but not exactly signing out the user from the application. User can simply click on the account without entering the credentials to sign in again.
var accounts = await publicClient.GetAccountsAsync();
          
var account =  accounts?.FirstOrDefault()
               
if (account != null)
{                   
    //
    // Remove the specific signed-in account from the cache
    //
    await publicClient.RemoveAsync(account);
}

This call:
await publicClient.RemoveAsync(account)

makes sure that the token is invalidated, but I want to also log the user out from the Microsoft account, so upon re-login, entering credentials would be necessary.

Any update on the issue?

To logout from the account and make the user to provide credentials again, construct a logout URL and modify the code like below:
To sign in the user and generate the access token and logout the user I used the below code:
Logout URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={redirectUri}
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

namespace AzureAdConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string clientId = "ClientID"; 
        private static string tenantId = "TenantID"; 
        private static string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" }; 
        private static string redirectUri = "http://localhost"; 

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}")
                .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
                .Build();

            AuthenticationResult result;

            try
            {
                var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
                var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

                if (firstAccount != null)
                {
                       result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {result.AccessToken}");
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {result.AccessToken}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
            }

            // Add logout functionality
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'L' to logout, or any other key to exit...");
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.L)
            {
                var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
                var account = accounts.FirstOrDefault();

                if (account != null)
                {
                    // Remove the account from the cache
                    await app.RemoveAsync(account);

                    // Construct the logout URL
                    var logoutUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={redirectUri}";

                    // Open the logout URI in the default web browser
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        FileName = logoutUri,
                        UseShellExecute = true
                    });

                    Console.WriteLine("User logged out. Please check your browser.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No account found to logout.");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

First the user singed in successfully and generated access token:

Now I pressed L to sign-out:

The user will be redirected to browser again to logout:

Select the account to sign-out and the user will be redirected to redirect page.

Now when I tried to sign in the user again, it asked me for credentials:


Its signing out my account from the browser ( chrome in my case ), not from the desktop application. When i relogin using the same app instance (var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create), my account still says signed in . Kindly advise

Try this URL https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/logout?client_id=ClientID&post_logout_redirect_uri=RedirectURL check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78276503/programatically-signing-out-of-a-azure-identity-application

Try to delete the token file and then sign out the user and the user will be signed out. Let me know if it works

Otherwise go with Microsoft Graph API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-invalidateallrefreshtokens?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example

I used this URL ( no redirect in my case )
var logoutUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?client_id={clientId}";
It opens the browser and says you are logged out from your account ( no list of account for selection ), but upon relogin, still i can my logged out account with status signed in.
It appears they are not synced, browser one is looking for the browser account, other is showing windows/desktop related signed in account

This issue usually occurs when the token is still valid and hence you need to clear the token cache that is when a user signs out, you should remove the tokens associated with that user from the token cache All the user related token cache must be cleared with logout URL and then it will work.

But i am doing this
await publicClient.RemoveAsync(account);

Are you storing in local cache?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
